# Aligning html inputs on same line 2

Tags: c#, html, css, styles, inline

I have the same behavior from many similar questions here.

But I tried anything and nothing happens to me.

I have 2 html controls. One anchor tag and a input button.

I applied vertical-align:top; float:right; display:inline-block;  independently and together and nothing happens.

When I click on Close, I see a shadow like a button! I want them inline both controls

[image: Buttons]

At the end of table I incluided a Div like this.

```
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnInput" runat="server" Text="Add selected"></asp:Button><a href="#">Close</a>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a width for each element when you make them `display:inline-block`, otherwise they default to 100%.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pJdjY/) with the closest equivalent markup I could make. (asp buttons don't work)

Comment: That solved my problem! Thanks a lot! I applied the display:inline-block to the anchor tag and perfect!

Answer (score 2):

As Dolchio said, every element must have `display: inline-block` for this to work. Note that your `float:right` will not achieve anything helpful in this scenario.

Try adding the CssClass attribute to the asp button and styling that class.

So it would look like `<asp:Button ID="btnInput" runat="server" CssClass="myButton" Text="Add selected"></asp>` and in your css `myButton{display:inline-block,vertical-align: top, width: 200px` substitute width for whatever the width of the button is (not entirely familiar with asp buttons and their implied widths).